# How to refresh all sections of .net configuration one time or how to iterate through them?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, configuration, configuration-files

There are some method called
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("..............");

It used to refresh sections in .net config for example: ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

I need to refresh all sections of config one time, i have some idea:
To iterate through them using LINQ or something like that, but how to do that!

Comment: Is this for testing scenarios? Config files tend to contain pretty immutable settings. If you use them for other purposes this may (may!) indicate that you should consider a different approach altogether.

Comment: Why do you need to refresh your configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider configuration as a [dependency](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/configuration-settings-are-a-dependency-that-should-be-injected). So, in stead of having calls to `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` etc. scattered in your application code, start communicating with a `Configuration` object that is 'injected' in your application. This can be done by dependency injection, if you have an IoC container running, or just by reading it by `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration()`.

This way, you can replace the whole `Configuration` object any time you want, in stead of refreshing sections.